# how to query out entries with a field of blank array by mongoid?

Tags: arrays, mongoid

my model is:(with mongoid version2)

```
class Trip
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes

  field :images, :type => Array, :default => []
end
```

i can search out entries, which its images size is not 0 by:

```
Trip.where(:images.size => 1).size #=>1, correct
```

while this method can not used for searching blank array field:

```
Trip.where(:images.size => 0).size #=>0, error, as i do have many entries with default [] field.
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following test verifies that the latest edit by @rubish works.

```
Trip.all.or(:images.size => 0).or(:images => nil)
```

test/unit/trip_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class TripTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    Trip.delete_all
  end

  test "criteria or" do
    Trip.create(:images => nil)
    Trip.create(:images => [])
    Trip.create(:images => ['xyzzy'])
    assert_equal(3, Trip.count)
    puts "Trip.all images:#{Trip.all.to_a.map(&:images).inspect}"
    trips_with_images_empty_or_nil = Trip.all.or(:images.size => 0).or(:images => nil).to_a
    puts "trips_with_images_empty_or_nil images: #{trips_with_images_empty_or_nil.map(&:images).inspect}"
    assert_equal(2, trips_with_images_empty_or_nil.size)
  end
end
```

test output

```
Run options: --name=test_criteria_or

# Running tests:

Trip.all images:[nil, [], ["xyzzy"]]
trips_with_images_empty_or_nil images: [nil, []]
.

Finished tests in 0.009099s, 109.9022 tests/s, 219.8044 assertions/s.

1 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following query, I hope it should work:

```
Trip.all.or(:images.size => 0).or(:images => nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my solution which may be helpful (latest syntax as well):

```
scope :without_images, -> { any_of(:images.with_size => 0, images: nil) }
```